# Resize/Move RAID 1 Partitions in Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have a client who didn't heed my warnings to compress/archive data, and now they've managed to fill a 4TB HD (ack) and now it won't boot due to no space left on /home for temp files.

The good news is, the drive is partitioned so we can steal enough space from /boot to get into the system and fix the mess.

The setup is:

- software RAID-1
- Kubuntu Linux 12.04LTS
- md0 = sda/b1 @ 50GB, /boot
- md1 = sda/b2 @ 4GB, swap
- md2 = sda/b3 @ remaining 3.9TB, /home

I'm hesitant on doing this because I don't want to break anything. For example, I've read that the start of the partition must not change. Can anybody tell me how to:

1. shrink md0 by 20GB
2. shift the unallocated 20GB to the end of the drive
3. add the 20GB to md2

I've already ran e2fsck on /dev/md0 and /dev/md2 - all clean (thankfully)

I *think* the process is:

1. fail all 3 RAID arrays
2. move stuff around using rescue disk or fdisk (Note: partitions are set as raid autodetect)
3. re-create the arrays

All my searching shows how to shrink an array, but doesn't discuss moving partitions.

Comment: I wouldn't break your arrays for this.  You could boot rescue mode and move some files to external media.  Do you mean md0 is `/` aka `root`not `/boot` if not where is root '/'.

Comment: Whoa! What great timing! Moments before you sent that, I arrived at the same conclusion. The transfer is taking place as I type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're showing your raid arrays but not the real partitions which are essential to know your setup.

That said, going through the trouble and risks involved, including human error, sounds like a bad solution altogether, especially for 20GB on a 4TB drive.

If I were you, I'd simply apply the initial recommendation to compress their files until the system can be booted normally and then have them compress, backup and cleanup their stuff, or add another drive.